# How to add indentation in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, indentation

I wrote the following script:

```
while read ligne;
do 
    echo ${ligne} >> /tmp/test.conf; 
    other code lines but it's not our probem.
done  < <(cat file.conf | sed -ne '/toto/,$p');
```

file.conf contain data like it:

```
test1 {
  var2 {}
}
toto {
  var1 {
    next {}
  }
}
```

the script must write in a file /tmp/test.conf

```
toto {
  var1 {
    next {}
  }
}
```

with the indentation.

Today I arrive to have this result:

```
toto {
var1 {
next {}
}
}
```

I try to modify my script by adding IFS variable like that:

```
(IFS='\n';
while read ligne;
do 
    echo ${ligne} >> /tmp/test.conf; 
    other code lines but it's not our probem.
done  < <(cat file.conf | sed -ne '/toto/,$p'));
```

I have the indentation but all the n letter in the result has been deleted.

```
toto {
  var1 {
    ext {}
  }
}
```

Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Get in the habit of quoting variables unless specifically **want** the value to go through word splitting and wildcard expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this loop with `IFS=` before `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r ligne; do
   echo "$ligne" >> /tmp/test.conf
done < <(sed -ne '/toto/,$p' file.conf)
```

OR else make sure of internal variable `REPLY`:

```
while read; do
   echo "$REPLY" >> /tmp/test.conf
done < <(sed -ne '/toto/,$p' file.conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

IFS must be set to an empty string, not to newline:

```
(IFS='';
while read ligne;
do 
    echo ${ligne} >> /tmp/test.conf; 
    # other code lines but it's not our probem.
done  < <(cat file.conf | sed -ne '/toto/,$p'));
```

Comment: @shellter that happens when the variable is split on `IFS` and passed as multiple arguments to echo. With `IFS=''`, it won't split.